# mongodb update operation with aggregation pipeline results in error code 14

Tags: mongodb

i'm trying to update the value of a field with the value of another field of a document. mongodb docs say it's possible by using an aggregation pipeline as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#update-with-aggregation-pipeline).

even the sample code from the docs results in an `TypeMismatch` code 14 error.

**command:**

```java
db.members.update(
   { },
   [
      { $set: { status: "Modified", comments: [ "$misc1", "$misc2" ] } },
      { $unset: [ "misc1", "misc2" ] }
   ],
   { multi: true }
)
```

**result:**

```java
WriteCommandError({
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1561779602, 1),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "BSON field 'update.updates.u' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'object'",
    "code" : 14,
    "codeName" : "TypeMismatch",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1561779602, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
})
```

is this an actual bug in mongodb or am i missing something?

Comment: Can you tell me your mongodb version?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti server is 4.0.6

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think what you are facing is a mongodb version issue.

According to the official documentation :

> **Update with Aggregation Pipeline**
>
> Starting in **MongoDB 4.2**, the `db.collection.update()` can use an
>   aggregation pipeline for the update. The pipeline can consist of the
>   following stages:
>
> - `$addFields` and its alias `$set`
> - `$project` and its alias `$unset`
> - `$replaceRoot` and its alias `$replaceWith`.

You can see that this support is available from **mongodb version 4.2**, And thats why it is throwing you that error.

Comment: ah yes... i missed that bit of info. thanks for the answer!

Comment: I have the same problem but I am using 4.2, what now?
> version()
4.2.0

Comment: Sorry.  Turns out the version was coming from the shell, not the database which is version 4.0.8

Comment: @SpacedMonkey so, were you able to update the version and resolve the issue? or do you still need help with something?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti I updated to the new version and it worked just as it should, thanks

Comment: Somehow I am facing this issue with version 4.2.3