# Spring: Update MongoDB with existing field

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

In Spring Boot I want to update a field in collection using other field from that collection.
I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
public void setTypeOfPayment(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
    Query query = new Query();
    Criteria paymentTypeFilter1 = Criteria.where("payment_type").is("SOME1");
    Criteria paymentTypeFilter2 = Criteria.where("payment_type").is("SOME2");
    query.addCriteria(paymentTypeFilter1.orOperator(paymentTypeFilter2));
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("payment.type_of_payment", "$payment_type");
    mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Report.class);
  }
```

I want to put existing `payment_type` value into `payment.type_of_payment` but I only get string `$payment_type`.
Is there a way to achieve this?
Update: my MongoDb version is 4.0.6.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the recent versions of spring data MongoDB, you can try using `AggregationUpdate` like this:

```
public void setTypeOfPayment(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
    Query query = new Query();
    Criteria paymentTypeFilter1 = Criteria.where("payment_type").is("SOME1");
    Criteria paymentTypeFilter2 = Criteria.where("payment_type").is("SOME2");
    query.addCriteria(paymentTypeFilter1.orOperator(paymentTypeFilter2));
    AggregationUpdate update = AggregationUpdate.update().set("payment.type_of_payment")
                .toValueOf("payment_type")
    mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Report.class);
}
```

Comment: I experienced this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56814957/mongodb-update-operation-with-aggregation-pipeline-results-in-error-code-14. It is because my MongoDb version is 4.0.6. However, thanks for answer. It will serve me to convince my admin to update MongoDb version.

Comment: In the current version, you can do it, by fetching all the documents, looping over and updating them in java, and then using saveAll method of repository

Comment: You can do that in each version, but that is not good way of doing bulk updates.

Comment: Yeah, not the best way, but the worst-case scenario.